# what to override for manipulating component addition in mxml

Tags: apache-flex

I have the following mxml code: (the MDI class extends Group)

```
<uiframe:MDI id="mdi" >
    <s:DataGrid />
    <s:DataGrid x="200" />
</uiframe:MDI>
```

Basically **I want to replace the DataGrids** with a Panel, what contains the DataGrid.

I tought this will help: (in MDI)

```
public override function addElement(element:IVisualElement):IVisualElement{
    replace(element); //replace does not get called
    return element;
}
```

but its not getting called when adding by MXML.

**UPDATE**: this works now, but I don't think its the best solution.

```
override protected function createChildren():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < super.numElements; i++){
        var e:IVisualElement = removeElementAt(0);
        addMyType(e); //converts to what I want..
    }
    super.createChildren();         
}
```

Comment: Where is your addElement function?  Is it in the MDI component?  Or elsewhere?  The replace method is not a method on a group; so what is the code behind that?  Where is the code where you try to replace the DataGrid with a Panel?

Comment: edited question. yes, it was in the MDI. its actually not replace, but that represents the code, where I make my transfromation to Panel. It looks like something in the updated section of the code.

Comment: I believe the components you add through MXML are added throug SkinnableContainer's (or any other container, like Group) `mxmlContent` setter. This does not call `addElement()`.

Comment: FYI csomakk: For containers, the equivalent of addElement is elementAdded - and its in the layout class for the container, not the container itself.